# What does $P(a)\cdot 1-P(a)$ actually mean.

Tags: probability

What does $P(a)\cdot (1-P(a))$ actually mean? Probability of something happening times the probability for something not to happen?

Wonder where does denominator of the correlation formula come from
$$\frac{P(A B)-P(A)P(B)}{\sqrt{P(A)(1-P(A))\cdot P(B)(1-P(B))}}$$

Saw this in binomial and correlation.

Comment: Can you give us more context? Presumably you saw something like $P(A)\times(1-P(A)$, where $1-P(A)=P(A)^c$, or perhaps $p\times(1-p)$, but it's rather hard to figure out what you mean without more precise parameters.

Comment: Please show a typographically accurate reference, and usage in full context.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be an event, and $\mathbf 1_A$ the indicator random variable for that event.   That is a random variable realising a value of $1$ when the event occurs, and $0$ otherwise.

By definition of indicator random variable, expectation, and variance, we see that:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_A)&=1\cdot \mathsf P(A)+0\cdot(1-\mathsf P(A))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(A)\\[2ex]\mathsf E({\mathbf 1_A}^2) &= 1^2\cdot\mathsf P(A)+0^2\cdot(1-\mathsf P(A))\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(A)\\[2ex]\mathsf {Var}(\mathbf 1_A)&=\mathsf E({\mathbf 1_A}^2)-\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_A)^2\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(A)-\mathsf P(A)^2\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(A)\cdot(1-\mathsf P(A))\end{align}$$

So there you have it.   The product, $\mathsf P(A){\cdot}(1-\mathsf P(A))$, represents the 'variance for the event' (although, more strictly, it is for the *indicator of* the event).   You might encounter this represented as simply $\sigma_A^2$ rather than $\sigma_{\mathbf 1_A}^2$.

This variance is a minimum ($0$) when the event is either *certain* or *impossible* (or at least, zero-probable).   It is a maximum ($1/4$), when the event is as likely as not to occur [$\mathsf P(A)=1/2$].

---

Similarly, we can evaluate the 'covariance', and hence 'correlation' between two events (or rather, their indicators).

$$\begin{align}\sigma_{\small A,B}&=\mathsf {Cov}(\mathbf 1_A, \mathbf 1_B)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_A\mathbf 1_B)-\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_A)\cdot\mathsf E(\mathbf 1_B)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A)\cdot\mathsf P(B)\\[2ex]\rho_{\small A,B}&=\mathsf {Corr}(\mathbf 1_A,\mathbf 1_B)\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\sigma_{\small A,B}}{\sqrt{\sigma_{\small A}^2\cdot\sigma_{\small B}^2}}\\[1ex]&=\dfrac{\mathsf P(A\cap B)-\mathsf P(A)\cdot\mathsf P(B)}{\sqrt{\mathsf P(A)~(1-\mathsf P(A))~\mathsf P(B)~(1-\mathsf P(B))}}\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer in such detail. Very satisfy with your explanation.

Comment: You might want to select it as the answer if so to help others.